# AWS account root user not able to query Athena tables

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-athena

I have logged into AWS as the root account and still unable to query a Athena table that was created by another IAM User having Administrator Role. When I log off and login in as the IAM User which created the Tables, I am able to query.

Any inputs how can I grant permission to the AWS Root Account to the Athena Table (also available in the Glue Catalog) ?

Comment: Amazon Athena uses the permissions of the currently logged-in user to access the Amazon S3 bucket. It seems very unlikely that the 'root user' would not have access to the objects in S3. You could check this by going to the S3 management console and trying to download some of the objects. Is the query possibly accessing data in a bucket that belongs to a _different_ AWS Account?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein The root user has access to the underlying objects in s3. I was also able to download one of the files to test your hypothesis. Also, it's the same account. It may be something to do with Lakeformation, but I am not sure what's the issue here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was because, the Admin role had not been granted access in Lakeformation to the given database which was being queried. Once, Admin role was assigned, the Account Owner was able to query the tables in the given database from Athena.